# publishing location using tf broadcast

Tags: ros

I am having a little problem using `tf::TransformListener` with the following method call:

```
listener.lookupTransform("/base_footprint", "/odom", ros::Time(0), transform);
```

I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1430761593.614566598, 10.000000000]: "base_footprint" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

I thought it was because I have not used a tf broacaster, but even with it the problem still remain. What am I doing wrong?

The code for the listener:

```cpp
tf::TransformListener listener;
ros::Rate rate(1.0);
listener.waitForTransform("/base_footprint", "/odom", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0));
tf::StampedTransform transform;
try 
{            
    listener.lookupTransform("/base_footprint", "/odom", ros::Time(0), transform);
    double x = transform.getOrigin().x();
    double y = transform.getOrigin().y();
    ROS_INFO("Current position: ( %f , %f)\n",x,y);
}
catch (tf::TransformException &ex)
{
    ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
}
```

The code for the broadcaster:

```cpp
ros::Time current_time, last_time;
tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;

double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
double th = 0.0;

double vx = 0.1;
double vy = -0.1;
double vth = 0.1;

current_time = ros::Time::now();
double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();
double delta_x = (vx * cos(th) - vy * sin(th)) * dt;
double delta_y = (vx * sin(th) + vy * cos(th)) * dt;
double delta_th = vth * dt;

x += delta_x;
y += delta_y;
th += delta_th; 

geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

//send the transform
odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

last_time = current_time;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the only tf publisher you are using (e.g. no [`joint_state_publisher`](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) or other publishers), I suggest you to have a look at [tf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials). Especially to this one: [robot setup](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF).

As you can find [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Transformations#Retrieving_Frame_Poses_and_Transforms), `lookupTransform(std::string &W, std::string &A, ros::Time &time, StampedTransform &transform)` stores in `transform` the transformation which lead you from frame A to frame W.

In your example you are tring to get the transform from `"/odom"` to `"/base_footprint"`, while the publisher is broadcasting the transform between `"/base_link"` and `"/odom"` (i.e. `"/base_footprint"` is not specified). It should be fine to use the same name (e.g. both `"/base_link"` or `"/base_footprint"` if they represent the same frame as I have supposed).

Also, be aware that in your publisher you are broadcasting the transformation **from** `"/base_link"` **to** `"/odom"` and not the opposite (as you might want).

**EDIT:** if you are using an .urdf model for your robot, please add it in your question or post the tf tree.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running the next command in your terminal to make sure your frames are correct, and that their are being broadcast. When we run your listener you should be able to graphically see you \base_footprint transforming into \odom:

```
rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree
```